# Safe to append to req parameter?

Tags: node.js, express

In express, when I use routing middleware, is it OK to append to the request object? Or is it a bad pattern? Alternatives? Thanks.

```
app.get('/', getLayout, function(req, res){
    if(req.layout == 'simple') ...render simple layout...
    else ...render full layout...
});
```

where

```
getLayout = function(req, res, next){
    req.layout = (req.params.blah == 'blah') ? 'layout_simple' : 'layout_full';
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you shouldn't.

I do it a lot.

I am under the impression this is what middleware typically does.

From the express docs:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

They set req.user in their middleware as the current user.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with j_mcnally that this is a fine pattern as long as you don't go overboard. Specifically, I append most things that are more closely related to the response to the `res` object. This would be things like layout info, HTML fragments, my intermediate jsdom env representation of the response, etc. For `req`, tacking on things that are representations of query string or request body info makes sense. This would be things like input parameters, parsed search queries, the current user object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The express docs suggest it's somewhat a standard practice:

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware

But it can significantly effect performance because of the way V8 works:

http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/03/javascript-memory-optimization-and.html

http://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript